# How exactly does the pre-load of assets on CDN endpoints work?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cdn

I'm working on trying to [pre-load our assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-preload-endpoint) onto our CDN profile, but I'm having issues understanding/proving whether it's working or not. After following the instructions in the documentation, I waited about an hour before logging into a VPN to test, and found that my file wasn't cached (didn't have the appropriate response headers). So my first couple questions are:

1. Does doing the pre-load process hit all the edge nodes?
2. How long does that process actually take?
3. Are there any settings in my blob storage that could prevent the
   files from being cached?

I'm using the Azure.ResourceManager.Cdn package to do this in C#, and I have gotten a `200` response, but even after waiting hours, when I ping a file, it doesn't seem as if it is cached.